# Chat Seems to be Down

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, 500-server-error

When I view any URL under https://chat.stackexchange.com, I get the following error:

[image]

It was working about 10 minutes ago.

When attempting to access https://chat.stackexchange.com, I get redirected to https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/. This is true regardless of whether I connect with HTTP or HTTPS.

Can anyone repro this?

Comment: [On a related note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367808/chat-seems-to-be-borked), `chat.stackoverflow.com` has been down for about an hour.

Comment: `chat.meta.stackexchange.com` is still up.

Answer (score 15):

We've solved the problem in the short-term. We're looking into the long-term solution.

We'll have a postmortem report when everything is completely fixed.  The short version was a lack of disk space but, of course, that's just part of the whole story.

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Archiving strategies incoming?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be back up now, along with Stack Overflow chat.