# Inconsistencies in rejected edits count

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, rejected-edits

I wanted to see all of my rejected edits in stack overflow.
After looking at the post [How can I see all my rejected edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85193/how-can-i-see-all-my-rejected-edits), I saw I have 8 rejected edits (user id 2359227 [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits#resultSets)):

[image]

However, when looking at the stats of a successful review, I see I have 12 rejected edits(An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27218511)):

[image]

The first question, is which one of the 2 is correct? Do I have 12 rejected edits, or only 8? In case I have 12, how can I see the other 4?

My assumption will be that the 4 rejected edits, are on posts that were deleted. If that is the case, why are they still counted? Approved edits of deleted posts are reduced from the posts edited count, and removing the 2 points earned for successful edit. Why aren't those deleted from the rejected edits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are tricked by the weekly SEDE refresh. The databases for all sites are refreshed one-by-one starting at Sunday 03:00 UTC. That takes a while. To be precise, it took [till 10:08:06 UTC](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc?cachebreaker=202009271252&bypassCache=true) until the last database, which happens to be Stack Overflow, was complete. You posted your question on 10:14:49 UTC.

Your screenshot and current SEDE result set confirm that. The edits that were added are the ones from last week.

Keep in mind that SEDE only keeps a table PostsWithDeleted but all other tables are sanitized for deleted posts, including suggestedits. It is hard if not impossible to compare counts from your profile and SEDE once deleted posts are involved.

I have a pending [Pull Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315014/improvements-to-data-updated-x-hours-days-ago-message-in-sede/354134#354134) to better inform users a restore is under way. Unfortunately that got code review feedback from Nick Craver so I have to revisit the PR in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the info! How can I know when does this cycle starts? And how much time should it take?

Comment: It starts always at 03:00 UTC on Sunday. It ends when the stackoverflow data is finished and that is roughly 7 hours later (takes a bit  longer each week due to increased data size). I linked to the status query in my answer